# "ember is not defined" while using torii authentication

Tags: javascript, npm, ember.js, google-oauth, torii

I am building a web app using ember js which includes google oauthand torii for authentication.. without torii being installed everything looks fine yet when i just installed torii(i never used it) the app crashes and it says `ember not defined` also there are depraction messages which are

```
See https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x/#toc_ember-global for details.

Usages of the Ember Global may be caused by an outdated ember-cli-babel dependency. The following steps may help:

* Upgrade the following addons to the latest version:
  * torii

### Important ###

In order to avoid repeatedly showing the same deprecation messages, no further deprecation messages will be shown for usages of the Ember Global until ember-cli-babel is upgraded to v7.26.6 or above.

To see all instances of this deprecation message, set the `EMBER_GLOBAL_DEPRECATIONS` environment variable to "all", e.g. `EMBER_GLOBAL_DEPRECATIONS=all ember test`.      

### Details ###

Prior to v7.26.6, ember-cli-babel sometimes transpiled imports into the equivalent Ember Global API, potentially triggering this deprecation message indirectly, even when you did not observe these deprecated usages in your code.

The following outdated versions are found in your project:

* ember-cli-babel@6.18.0, currently used by:
  * torii@0.10.1
    * Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.11.0
```

`ember version : 4.6.0`
`torii version : 0.10.1`

Comment: looks like someone needs to take over maintenance of Torii: https://github.com/Vestorly/torii
It hasn't had an update merged in a while and it seems not compatible with Ember v4.

what does npm/yarn why torii show? (where is it being brought in?)

Comment: Can you suggest me an alternative or a way to use Google sign in on ember?? Or shall I start a new thread asking the same?

Comment: have you seen https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth it has an oauth provider

Comment: yeah but i couldnt invoke the sign in prompt and get user details from it.. are there other documentation??.. cause everything i saw used torii as bearer service and ember-simple-auth for session management